# Do traps improve when you level the ability after you place them?

Tags: league-of-legends

For example, if I place a [Yordle Snap Trap](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/ability/yordle-snap-trap-341) and then put a point into that ability, will the placed snap trap benefit from the higher level when it is activated?

Comment: I know that spells check level when they're triggered (try leveling up a spell mid-flight!) , but I'm not sure if, for traps, that means when they're placed or when they go off.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a couple of champions who have "latent" trap-like abilities. Testing has indicated that most *already placed traps* benefit from leveling up, but others (specifically Maokai's saplings) do **not** benefit from leveling it up.

#### TLDR:

- Nidalee's traps scale retroactively
- Teemo's shrooms scale retroactively
- Shaco's JackInTheBox scales retroactively
- Catilyn's traps scale retroactively.

---

- Maokai's saplings do *not* scale retroactively. Poor outlier Maokai.

**Original Answer**

I coerced my friend [FallenAngelEyes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/160/fallenangeleyes) into helping me test this out with Maokai and his saplings (alas, I do not own Caitlyn).

[image]

This is from the level 1 sapling. Nasus takes 64 damage.

I then threw another sapling, then, after it was thrown, leveled up Throw Sapling to level 2.

[image]

This did 63 damage, so leveling up sapling toss after the sapling is already in the world has no effect. **Compared to later testing, THIS IS THE EXCEPTION!**

(Note:That sneaky Nasus gained a level between tests, and increased his magic resistance enough to mitigate 1 damage! Jerk.)

Finally, I threw a 3rd sapling, from level 2, to establish a baseline at the second rank. As expected, it did more damage.

[image]

---

But one ability on one champion doesn't tell the whole story. I then re-ran the tests with **Teemo** and his traps, and leveling the ability *did* update existing traps. Teemo and Maokai got different results!

Shaco, Caitlyn, and Nidalee's traps all scale retroactively as well.

**The behavior seems intended that traps scale retroactivley - 'tis only Maokai (who was, unfortunately, the first one we tested) that doesn't adhere to this.**

Comment: Just as extra information: All of them will use your current Armor/Magic penetration when the trap is triggered (rather than using your penetrations when it's placed). Kind of obvious, but thought it should be explicit :-)

Comment: Perhaps "Testing of this is still ongoing, but preliminary results would indicate that already placed traps do not benefit from leveling it up." ought to be removed, considering you've since discovered it's the other way around.