# When are Teemo's bomb's damage calculated?

Tags: league-of-legends

This is something I've often wondered when playing Teemo.  If I place a bomb, and then an enemy walks over it seven minutes later, how is the damage calculated?  Is it based off of how much AP and what items I had *when I placed it*, or is it instead calculated off of my stats *at the time the enemy triggers it*?

Comment: Based on [this similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50543/do-traps-improve-when-you-level-the-ability-after-you-place-them), I would assume that Teemo's traps deal damage based on AP when triggered.

Comment: Cool question!  That only deals with leveling abilities up, though, and doesn't address changing items/statistics.  But that may be a valid assumption.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Damage in League of Legends is calculated "just in time". That is, there are no damage calculations performed until the game has confirmed that a unit has taken damage.

This has a couple of interesting ramifications. For instance, if you level up a projectile or projectile skill shot *while the projectile is in flight*, it will do the damage of the new rank, not the rank you had when you triggered it.

It also means that Teemo's shrooms only calculate their damage when they trigger, and that all placed shrooms are always at identical power, regardless of *when* they were placed.

Comment: While Teemo's mushrooms do benefit from leveling up, they do not benefit from increased ability power at a later time (specifically when detonated).

Comment: @Yawus I have just double checked, and there is no question -- mushroom damage updates as soon as Teemo's ability power changes.

Comment: This is the same reason you can fire Acid Hunter as Urgot, then activate Terror Capacitor while it is in flight to have it slow the target when it hits.