# When does Janna's extra AD from her shield take effect?

Tags: league-of-legends

Janna's E is a shield that also grants the shielded champion bonus AD.

If a champion uses a skillshot and gains the shield after the skillshot is fired but before it hits an enemy, does the skillshot have the bonus AD or not?

Comment: The short answer is, if the shield is on before the skillshot deals damage, you get the boost.

Comment: See also my answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97694/336