# Level up abilities while using them

Tags: league-of-legends

What happens when I level up abilities (like Garen's W (Judgment), Morgana's W and E (Tormented Soil, Black Shield), etc...) while I am using them?

Does the damage increase instantly or the does the damage increase just in the next ability cast?

**Example:**

I am playing with Garen and use Garen's W (Judgment). While spinning, I level up and I increase Garen's W (Judgment) a level too. Does the effect of leveling up the ability happens while Garen stills spinning or the effect only will happen in the next Garen's W (Judgment)?

Comment: Related question: [Do traps improve when you level the ability after you place them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50543/145980)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All damage values in the game are calculated when the damage is supposed to take effect (i.e., not ahead of time, but "just in time"). This means if you level up a skill while it is currently being used, the remaining duration of the effect will have increased damage.

Another example would be the exhaust sumomner spell. Let's say champion X is using a ranged auto attack on another champion that would normally deal 100 damage. If X shoots the bullet and is then exhausted before the projectile reaches the target, the target will take 60 damage (40% less). On the other hand, if X shoots the projectile while exhausted, and the exhaust effect ends right before the projectile lands, the target will take the full 100 damage.

[Source](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3697140)

Comment: Another example: If you have a champion that can lay traps (e.g. Nidalee or Teemo) and go back to buy an item that adds effects to spells (e.g. Luden's Echo, Rylais or Liandrys Torment), all placed traps gain that effect. It's a bit more obvious than the exhaust example, since there are extra visual effects.

Comment: @hoffmale But traps are not "activated"  until someone steps in them. I like the example of an auto attack, much more obvious than traps

Comment: @TJ: auto attacks aren't "activated", either. They do damage when they hit the target. If your auto attack projectile is targeting a champion that just teleported away (requires a ranged champion), you could conceivably also buy an item affecting auto attacks (e.g. AD, crit, on-hit effect, but no on-attack effects) and verify that on your target. It's just a lot harder regarding timing and verification. That said, using auto attacks bypasses the whole "skill increase affects skill in use" issue. Also, traps could be activated before said purchase (the next dot tick applies the spell effects).

Comment: @hoffmale *auto attacks aren't "activated"*, either. That is my point. Traps are more complicated, so they are a bad example for this case. Auto attacks are simple, so they are a good example

Comment: This effect is very easy to check. Try to start casting Zac 'E' if you will have your jump prepared just lvl up your E. Range of your jump will be increased.